# NetSuite SuiteScript - create Deposit

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a Suitescript to create a Deposit. It works well in several NetSuite accounts where I have deployed it except for the most recent one. It returns the following error:

> USER_ERROR Please enter value(s) for: Department, Class

This is the sample of the script:

```
const rec = record.create({
    type: record.Type.DEPOSIT,
    isDynamic: true,
    defaultValues: {
        account: 1232,
    },
});

rec.setValue('trandate', new Date('01/29/2024'));

const additionalFields = [
    {'fieldId': 'department', 'fieldValue': '110'},
    {'fieldId': 'class', 'fieldValue': '201'}
]

if (additionalFields) {
    log.debug('info', 'setting additional fields');
    for (const x of additionalFields) {
        log.debug('set field', x.fieldId + ': ' + x.fieldValue);
        rec.setValue(x.fieldId, x.fieldValue);
    }
}

const applyPayments = ['575126']
if (applyPayments) {
    for (const x of applyPayments) {
        log.debug('lookup payment', x);
        const index = rec.findSublistLineWithValue({
            sublistId: 'payment',
            fieldId: 'id',
            value: x,
        });
        log.debug('payment', index);

        if (index == -1) {
            result = {
                error: {
                    code: 'NOT_FOUND',
                    detail: 'ID for supplied payment does not exist!',
                },
            };
            return result;
        } else {
            rec.selectLine({
                sublistId: 'payment',
                line: index,
            });

            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'payment',
                fieldId: 'deposit',
                value: true,
            });

            rec.commitLine({sublistId: 'payment'});
        }
    }
}

newRecordId = rec.save();
```

As you can see, I do set the Department and Class but somehow it is not recognized.
This is what the UI looks like:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the department and class you're trying to set available for the chosen subsidiary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the department and class you are using are allowed for the transaction's subsidiary then it's likely that the account also requires department and class at the line level.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thank you for replying.